# Cannot convert from 'void' to 'object' Button OnClick in Asp Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I want to run the Like method when I click on a button. But when I compile I get a "Cannot convert from 'void' to 'object'" error.
Here is my code:

```
<button onclick=@Like(item)> @item.likes</button>

@{
void Like(Link link){
    link.likes = link.likes + 1;
    _context.Update(link);
    _context.SaveChanges();
}
}
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: How could it be possible (without using Blazor) to bind a server-side C# function to a client-side event?

Comment: This is not how web works.  By the time the button gets clicked, there is no C# code to run, because the C# code lives on the server and your button is in a clients browser page.  You can call a method on the server using xhr.

Answer (score 0):

You don’t use OnClick events when working on web apps like asp.net to interact with the web server. You can use it for JavaScript but that’s client side as well.
OnClick is for native GUI apps or JavaScript.
For web apps you have to use submit form or a link, which will send a request to the server, and service that request through the Controller (if you’re working with asp.net core mvc or any MVC framework).